# How to concatenate an object property to another string or variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, concatenation

I want to concatenate an object property to a variable like this,

```
var foo = { bar_zen: 0, bar_jj: 0 }


var foo2 = $(this); // this comes from attr of an Id or class on click
if(foo.bar_+foo2+ == 0){ ..// do something }
```

Comment: Show the corresponding HTML as well. Also, `$(this)` does not correlate to an attribute or an id. It references an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use bracket notation instead of dots:

```
if(foo["bar_" + foo2] == 0){ ..// do something }
```